# Define a variable in JavaScript as a block

Tags: javascript

In Swift, I can do this to define a variable:

```
let foo: String = {
    if bar {
        return "42"
    } else {
        return "43"
    }
}()
```

How can I define a variable like this in JavaScript? I know that you can define a variable as undefined and redefine it in the if block, but that's an ugly syntax IMO, since "foo" would get repeated 3 times instead of 1 in the Swift example:

```
let foo

if (bar) {
    foo = "42"
} else {
    foo = "43"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're just setting the value conditionally you can use a ternary expression:

```js
const foo = bar ? '42' : '43'
```

You could use a function for more complex logic:

```js
let bar = true;
const foo = computeFoo(bar);

function computeFoo(bar) {
  if (bar) {
    return "42";
  }
  return "43";
}

console.log(foo); // 42
```

Or an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
let bar = true;
const foo = (() => {
  if (bar) {
    return "42";
  }
  return "43";
})()

console.log(foo); // 42
```

Answer (score 14):

If the logic is short enough you could use a conditional operator:

```
let foo = bar ? "42" : "43"
```

If the logic is more complicated, then i personally would do the last example you showed. But one other alternative you could consider is using an [immediately invoked function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
let foo = (() => {
  if (bar) {
    return "42"
  } else {
    return "43"
  }
})()
```

This creates an anonymous function, calls it immediately, and then whatever it returns gets assigned to `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator:

```
let variable = true ? "A" : "B"
```

In you case:

```
let foo = bar ? '42' : '43'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a *frisson* to the answer set:

```js
const bar = false

let foo = (() => {
  switch(true) {
    case bar:
      return "42"
    default:
      return "43" 
  }
})()

console.log(foo) // 43
```

Answer (score 0):

let foo = bar ? '42' : '43'

[condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)